# Java Spring-BOOT: main-loop beside HTTP-handler

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am starting with Spring BOOT.

```
public class App 
{
    public static void main (String [] args) throws Exception
    {
        System.out.println ("--------------------");

        SpringApplication.run (App.class, args);

        for (;;)   // my main loop
        {
            // do something permanently
            Thread.sleep (10000);
        }    
    }  
}
```

Beside the HTTP-handler-conponents I have I like to have a main-loop (e.g. for doing tasks beside HTTP).

- Is this design with the loop the best way to do that?

I am using configuration-binding (@Value and @ConfigurationProperties too).

- How can I get that information in my main-loop? I can not do it with static variables.

Comment: You can do it with springBoot using @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 10000). Why do you want to do it outside spring? Scheduler example: https://spring.io/guides/gs/scheduling-tasks/

Comment: Its not my plan to do it outside. I just did not know how to do it inside.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [scheduler](https://spring.io/guides/gs/scheduling-tasks/) spring doc. Briefly:

Add @EnableScheduling to starter/config:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
public class SchedulingTasksApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SchedulingTasksApplication.class);
    }
}
```

example scheduler component:

```
@Component
public class ScheduledTasks {
    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 10000)
    public void reportCurrentTime() {
        // do anything
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Dont do anything like that in your Application class.

Just define a spring bean and annotate a function that contains whatever logic you want to have performed regularly and annotate is with an @Scheduled.

Have a look at the following for more information: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-scheduled-tasks

Answer (score 1):

I dont think this would be the better design.
If you wan to do the non HTTTP task then then i would recommend creating new bean and using  @Scheduled and can specify the time when you want to do it.

```
@Component
public class YourTask{
@Scheduled(fixedRate = 5000)
    public void reportCurrentTime() {
        //your task
    }
}
```